# how to concatenate different tensor shapes in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement Attention mechanism in keras my context_vector shape is shape=(?, 1024) 
And my decoder_embedding shape is shape=(?, 38, 1024) 
Both context_vector and decoder_embedding are tensors how can i concatenate these....?

```
def B_Attention_layer(state_h,state_c,encoder_outputs):

  d0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_1')
  d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_2')
  d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024,name='dense_layer_3')
  #below are the hidden states of LSTM 
  # my encoder output shape is shape=(?, 38, 1024)
  #my each hidden state shape is i.e.., state_c shape=(?, 1024) ,state_h shape=(?, 1024)
  hidden_with_time_axis_1 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(state_h, 1)
  hidden_with_time_axis_2 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(state_c, 1)
  score = d0(tf.keras.activations.tanh(encoder_outputs) + d1(hidden_with_time_axis_1) +  d2(hidden_with_time_axis_2))
  attention_weights = tf.keras.activations.softmax(score, axis=1)
  context_vector = attention_weights * encoder_outputs
  context_vector = tf.keras.backend.sum(context_vector, axis=1)
  input_to_decoder = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([context_vector,decoder_embedding])

  return input_to_decoder , attention_weights
```

When i'm trying this i'm getting a concatenation error like below

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 1, 1024), (None, 38, 1024)]
```

Comment: try `axis=1` in Concatenate layer?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation axis is 1 in your case, since you have shapes `(None, 1, 1024)` and `(None, 38, 1024)`
Example:

```
I1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1, 1024))
# <tf.Tensor 'input_6:0' shape=(?, 1, 1024) dtype=float32>
I2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(38, 1024))
# <tf.Tensor 'input_7:0' shape=(?, 38, 1024) dtype=float32>

concated = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([I1,I2])
# output: <tf.Tensor 'concatenate_4/concat:0' shape=(?, 39, 1024) dtype=float32>
```

Also as error message states since concatenation axis is 1 rest of the dimensions has to be same.